# JNI code to return string but gets error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.package.openGeoDb()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am deploying a program and encountered error of

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
com.package.JniClass.JniGeoDbReader.openGeoDb()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I managed to load the dll but I feel like something has caused the string to not be converted correctly and caused the error. The following is the JNI code I am currently testing to deploy on Karaf :

JNI Codes>>>JAVA and c++

**JniGeoDbReader.class**

```
package com.package.JniClass;

public final class JniGeoDbReader {

private JniGeoDbReader() { }

public static native String openGeoDb(); }
```

---

**ServiceClass.class** <--- This class is the simplified version

```
import com.package.JniClass.JniGeoDbReader;

public class ServiceClass{
  public void fetchResponse(){    
    System.load("D:\\DLL_PATH\\com_package_jniGeoDbReader.dll");
    LOGGER.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}", JniGeoDbReader.openGeoDb());
  }
}
```

---

**com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader */

#ifndef _Included_com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader
#define 
_Included_com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader
 * Method:    openGeoDb
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
 Java_com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader_openGeoDb
(JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

---

**dllmain.cpp** <--I got this code from somewhere else

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_package_JniClass_JniGeoDbReader_openGeoDb
(JNIEnv *env , jobject obj) {
   string message = "Welcome to JNI";
   int byteCount = message.length();
   const jbyte* pNativeMessage = reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*> 
       (message.c_str());
   jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(byteCount);
   env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, byteCount, pNativeMessage);

   // find the Charset.forName method:
   //   javap -s java.nio.charset.Charset | egrep -A2 "forName"
   jclass charsetClass = env->FindClass("java/nio/charset/Charset");
   jmethodID forName = env->GetStaticMethodID(
    charsetClass, "forName", " 
      (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;");
   jstring utf8 = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
   jobject charset = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(charsetClass, 
      forName, utf8);

  // find a String constructor that takes a Charset:
  //   javap -s java.lang.String | egrep -A2 "String\(.*charset"
   jclass stringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
   jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(
    stringClass, "<init>", "([BLjava/nio/charset/Charset;)V");

   jstring jMessage = reinterpret_cast<jstring>(
    env->NewObject(stringClass, ctor, bytes, charset));
   return jMessage; }
```

I got the code in the cpp from here: [Send C++ string to Java via JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621449/send-c-string-to-java-via-jni/24564937). I would like to do something similar, that is to return a string without accepting any parameters. But for some reason, it is throwing error. Please guide me in what causes this error and which part of this code I should change. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.fetchCatalogue(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.ArcGisDiscoveryJob$CatalogueTask.call(ArcGisDiscoveryJob.java:485)
    at com.package.ArcGisDiscoveryJob$CatalogueTask.call(ArcGisDiscoveryJob.java:450)
    at com.package.BaseTaskExecutor.invoke(BaseTaskExecutor.java:84)
    at com.package.ArcGisDiscoveryJob.traverse(ArcGisDiscoveryJob.java:131)
    at com.package.ArcGisDiscoveryJob.run(ArcGisDiscoveryJob.java:224)
    at com.package.BaseScheduler$1.run(BaseScheduler.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.package.JniClass.JniGeoDbReader.openGeoDb()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ArcGisClientProxy$1.call(ArcGisClientProxy.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.package.JniClass.JniGeoDbReader.openGeoDb()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.package.JniClass.JniGeoDbReader.openGeoDb(Native Method)
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ServiceClass.fetchResponse(ServiceClass.java:364)
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ServiceClass.fetchCatalogue(ServiceClass.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ArcGisClientProxy.callEndPoint(ArcGisClientProxy.java:241)
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ArcGisClientProxy.access$000(ArcGisClientProxy.java:32)
    at com.package.service.rest.impl.ArcGisClientProxy$1.call(ArcGisClientProxy.java:155)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is the stack trace? Does the VM maybe try to initialize `JniGeoDbReader` before `ServiceClass` can load the library?

Comment: @user2543253, I've updated the stack trace in the post :)

Comment: Somewhere along the liine you have changed the native method from instance to static, or vice versa, without regenerating the .h file.

Comment: Oh, I'll give a try again after regenerating the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file and your CPP code don't match. The header declares `jclass` for the second function parameter, but the implementation has `jobject`. JNI itself would not care because `jclass` is the same as `jobject`, but your compiler will not recognize the function, because of the different parameter declaration. Therefore it will not see the `extern "C"` for the function and export it with CPP name mangling, and Java will not find it.

Edit: hadn't seen @user207421's comment, and while it is important that you always regenerate the header file if something changes in your native method, it won't help in your case because your header already matches the Java code. You also have to change your implementation to match the header.

Comment: I made the change to the second parameter and it works. :) Thanks