# Android binary to handle root functions

Tags: java, android, c++, binary, root

Several apps on android market is utilizing some kind of binary and root to call android system methods which normally require permissions only granted to system apps (/system/app).

I am wondering if it is possible to call java methods with C++ binaries using JNI. Does anyone know how the apps are doing this? An example is the launcher Apex launcher, which uses root to allow users to add widgets with the new widgets screen on ICS.

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated

Comment: And what proof do you have that that function requires root?

Comment: For example, apex launcher. On ICS, adding widget with the new widget screen requires permission BIND_WIDGET only granted to system apps. However, there is an option to use "root helper" to bypass that

Comment: @kevdliu Have you figured anything out yet? I'd love to know how this is accomplished. Nova Launcher does a similar thing running some native code as root to access the AppWidgetManager APIs.

Comment: Not yet. But this is of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838397/how-do-i-load-my-own-java-class-in-c-on-android